# Which one is correct: "You've got no life of/for" your own?

Tags: prepositions

"*Let's face facts here. You took care of your parents for so long, you've got no life **of** your own.*"

"*Let's face facts here. You took care of your parents for so long, you've got no life **for** your own.*"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please give your questions useful titles. “Which one is correct?” is completely generic, and it is impossible for anyone to guess what your question is actually about.

Comment: Either "... life of your own" or "... life for yourself".  Though they have slightly different connotations that I can't figure out how to explain at present.

Answer (score 1):

Not a native speaker but I'd say "... *life **of** your own*". Never heard the alternative, I think.

[Here's a Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=life%20of%20your%20own%2C%20life%20for%20your%20own&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clife%20of%20your%20own%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clife%20for%20your%20own%3B%2Cc0) that supports **of** over **for**

**Edit:** In the light of @Edwin's comment below, [here's a new Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no%20life%20of%20your%20own%2C%20no%20life%20for%20your%20own&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20life%20of%20your%20own%3B%2Cc0) that compares "no life of/for your own", which makes the point even more clear.

Comment: 'If you want a better life for your own family ...' is an obvious false positive. Why not Ngrams for "no life of your own" & "no life for your own" (which make the position clearer)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth good point, i'll edt

Answer (score 1):

Here, ***of*** suggests a sense of belonging and ***for*** suggests something that you are given with. Therefore, using ***of*** would create more meaning to the sentence.